# Compiler Error Message Customization

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, clang

I'm trying to get error numbers or error IDs printed with the error messages from my C compiler.  I am currently using GCC but if it would be easier using Clang, that would be okay too.

This is an example for an error message as I get it:

```
error: syntax error before '}' token
```

This is how I want it to be instead:

```
error(ERRID): syntax error before '}' token --
```

*`ERRID`* is a number or unique string for that error.

Is that possible with GCC or Clang? And if it is possible, how to do it?

I want this feature to make error messages searchable and identifiable for easy parsing and analyzing of errors.

Comment: Hmm.. Download gcc sources and modify them to your needs?

Comment: @EugeneSh. im hoping if this feature is already implemented in gcc, modifying gcc will really take a long time to learn.

Comment: You can read clang docs about `#error`

Comment: Why did you tag the question `clang`?  Would you be okay with a Clang solution too?  Not that I know one but Clang is not GCC.

Comment: @5gon12eder clang or gcc are fine if there is similar solution to clang i would take it.

Comment: @SohibAL-Gotimel That is quite relevant to your question so I have edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error messages are localized, you could change the error message catalog for your language to suite your needs.

Alternatively, you could modify some passes reporting the error e.g. with your plugin (or even some [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension).

But I am surprized you are asking, the GCC source code contains a catalog of error messages, in the [gcc/po/](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/po/) subdirectory of the source code.

Notice that the message catalog is using the [gettext(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gettext.3.html) machinery, so the message id is actually the English (C locale) message itself.